# How can a simple car front light make a rainbow like this?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, visible-light

I have observed this phenomenon at nighttime, when the sky was clear, there was no rain, no fog, no unusual level of humidity or anything else.

The car front light is a simple Nissan. It does or should not have a prism in it.

[image]

Question:

1. How can a simple car's front light make a rainbow on the asphalt without a prism or the presence of rain or fog?

Comment: from the glass in the headlight, at the edge, there must be an edge or some unusual geometry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's not quantum-mechanics exactly.  In effect what you are seeing is the edge of a lens where the angles make things very difficult to control. Eye-glasses can exhibit similar features.

https://www.2020mag.com/article/chromatic-aberration-the-end-of-the-rainbow

Note that you are viewing light that has traveled at different angles through the glass of the headlight. So it has very likely traveled through different thicknesses of glass, and entered and exited at different angles.

Answer (score 2):

There are clear plastics that are sufficiently dispersive that windows or lenses made from them will act like prisms and produce colored halos around bright light sources.

This is a common defect in inexpensive plastic eyeglass lenses and it is possible for the halos to degrade the sharpness of the lens to the point where the lens prescription is ruined.

To avoid this, one has to specify "low-dispersion" plastic when ordering plastic eyeglass lenses but they cost more. In the automotive world, they'll use the cheaper stuff and only physics nerds like us will ever notice the difference.